# How to handle IE10 touch events?

Tags: javascript, touch, windows-8

I know how to use the obtouchstart ontouchmove etc. events. But IE10 supports it in a different way. Are there any tutorial about it?

And how can I test it without a touchscreen win8?

Comment: Is your question "are there any tutorial about it?" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx

Comment: @Esailija thanks. But how can I test it?

Comment: Read the article... use the Pointer events.

Comment: @Esailija Write as an answer, because I can't accept a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tutorial about Pointer events which seems to normalize all kinds of pointers (touch, pen, mouse)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx